# NewRelic monitoring for Spring Boot application not tracking endpoints correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, newrelic

We have a Spring boot (v1.3.8) based application being monitored by New Relic APM, which uses projects like Spring Data & Spring Data Rest. New Relic configured as an agentlib.

In this applciation, we have certain endpoints like

```
/Employee/12345
/Employee/search/findEmployeesByDeptId?DeptId=12345
```

This end-point is bound to a Spring Data based "CRUDRepository".

The problem I have is that under New Relic, when it reports long running transactions, It aggregates all of those endpoints to one of the below

```
/RepositoryEntityController/getCollectionResource
/RepositoryEntityController/getItemResource
/RepositorySearchController/executeSearch
```

Is there a tweak such that the above aggregation reports some meaningful URLs rather than the above programs?

Answer (score 0):

By default the New Relic agent will use the Controller name plus the method as the transaction name.

You could try [disabling auto transaction naming](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/instrumentation/transaction-naming-protocol/#reverting) and see if the result works for you. Note the warning on that page.

Another way would be to use the [Java agent API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/api-guides/guide-using-java-agent-api/#transactions). Though in this case you'd need to add a line of code to each of your endpoints. Or do some wizardry in your servlet.

```
// see https://newrelic.github.io/java-agent-api/javadoc/index.html?com/newrelic/api/agent/NewRelic.html
NewRelic.setTransactionName("/Employee/" + employeeId);
```